# Get csproj path macros in file watcher in Rider

Tags: c#, rider, file-watcher

Is there a way to get a path to `.csproj` file in file watcher? I want to create a watcher that will launch third-party app with this argument. There is plenty of different macros (like solutionPath etc) but I didn't find what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a new custom tool, there are some project-related macros there:

```
File | Settings | Tools | Custom Tools
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. I'm trying to create a new watcher in a file watcher tool. And I need to pass a path to the current csproj file. But I have no clue how to get it dynamically.

Comment: You can setup custom tool instead of file watcher tool. Basically they do the same, but custom tools working inside R# part of Rider. While file watchers works on IDEA side...

Comment: My goal was to launch a third-party app on files changes automatically and pass it needed arguments. As I see I cannot do it via Custom tools, but correct me if I wrong.

Comment: Why you can not do that?

Comment: I have added an image to the answer

Comment: Thank you for further explanation. I feel stupid, but I still don't understand how to configure to run this tool automatically on files changes?

Comment: It should be executed on every file change (ctrl+s or autosave) for files with specified extension) if it does not - probably you have found a bug in Rider =)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a simple way, so I ended up with a python script. It finds a file path with some regexps specific to my project. And I have added a custom file watcher that launches this script when needed.